# Segmentation Fault ao executar comando pop em pilha dinâmica

Tags: c, stack, falha-de-segmentação

Estou tentando implementar uma pilha dinâmica mas o programa termina em erro ao executar a função desempilha(pop), retornando um Segmentation Fault. Não estou conseguindo entender o porquê.. Agradeço a ajuda

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char pilha_item;

struct pilha_no_struct { 
  pilha_item item;
  struct pilha_no_struct* prox;
};
typedef struct pilha_no_struct* pilha_no;

struct pilha_struct {
    unsigned quantidade;
    pilha_no topo;
};
typedef struct pilha_struct* pilha;

pilha inicializa()
{
    pilha nova_pilha = (pilha) malloc(sizeof(pilha));

    if (!nova_pilha)
        return (NULL);

    nova_pilha->quantidade = 0;
    nova_pilha->topo = NULL;

    return nova_pilha;
}

int vazia(pilha p)
{
    return p->quantidade == 0;
}

int empilha(pilha p, pilha_item item)
{
    if (vazia(p))
    {
        pilha_no novo_no = (pilha_no)malloc(sizeof(pilha_no));

        if (!novo_no)
            return (0);

        novo_no->item = item;
        novo_no->prox = NULL;

        p->topo = novo_no;
        p->quantidade++;

        return (1);
    }

    else
    {
        pilha_no novo_no = (pilha_no)malloc(sizeof(pilha_no));

        if (!novo_no)
            return (0);

        novo_no->item = item;
        novo_no->prox = p->topo;
        p->topo = novo_no;
        p->quantidade++;

        return (1);
    }
}

void elements(pilha p){
    
    while(p->topo){
        printf("%c", p->topo->item);
        p->topo = p->topo->prox;
    }
}
 
int desempilha(pilha p)
{
    if (vazia(p))
        return (0);

    else
    {   
        if(p->quantidade == 1){
            pilha_no temp = p->topo;
            p->topo = NULL;
            free(temp);
            return (1);
        }
        else{
            pilha_no temp = p->topo;
            p->topo = p->topo->prox;
            free(temp);
            return (1);
        }

    }
}


int main()
{
    pilha p = inicializa();
    empilha(p, 'S');
    empilha(p,'N');
    empilha(p, 'S');
    elements(p);
    desempilha(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seu programa está um pouco confuso, achei. Apenas nas primeiras 20 linhas aparece uma quantia impressionante de _pilha-isso_ _pilha-aquilo_. Acho que você não devia declarar --- typedef --- um ponteiro como pilha. Só gera confusão. E erro. Veja essa linha:   `pilha nova_pilha = (pilha)malloc(sizeof(pilha));` Tem 4 vezes a palavra pilha. E está alocando para a :D pilha a área de um ponteiro... Não é isso que quer...

Comment: Entendo o que você quer dizer! Mas isso é um exercício da faculdade que meu professor passou. Ele deu as estruturas já com os 'typedefs' e quer a implementação dessas funções.

Comment: Vou te mostrar um exemplo co seu código e me diz se entende o que eu quiz dizer... Entendeu  o erro na linha de que falei?

Answer (score 0):

Alterei seu código um pouco para mostrar do que eu estava falando

#### Sua estrutura

```
typedef char pilha_item;

struct pilha_no_struct {
    pilha_item item;
    struct pilha_no_struct* prox;
};
typedef struct pilha_no_struct* pilha_no;

struct pilha_struct {
    unsigned quantidade;
    pilha_no topo;
};
typedef struct pilha_struct* pilha;
```

Trata-se de uma pilha, um pilha tem nodes que contém itens. No seu caso está usando uma letrinha, mas podia ser um ponteiro para uma estrutura complexa

#### considere por exemplo a mesma coisa escrita assim

```
typedef char Item;

typedef struct _node_
{
  Item              item;
  struct    _node_* prox;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned    quantidade;
    Node*       topo;
}   Pilha;
```

Onde uma `Pilha` tem `Node` que tem `Item`.

Declare suas funções DEPOIS de `main()` e deixe apenas os protótipos na frente, ou ainda use um arquivo .h e separe tudo. É melhor para você e melhor para quem vai ler o seu programa. É chato ficar procurando pela função em meio ao código.

E adote alguma convenção para identificar seus tipos. Eu usei como exemplo a primeira letra em maiúscula.

Sobre as funções, porque não usou os nomes clássicos, `push()` `pop()` `top()` `empty()` `size()` ?

#### um exemplo

Considere esse programa:

```
int main()
{
    Pilha* pilha = inicializa();
    elements(pilha);
    for (char item = 'a'; item <= 'z'; item += 1)
        pilha = empilha(&item, pilha);
    elements(pilha);
    while (!vazia(pilha))
    {   mostra(pilha);
        desempilha(pilha);
    };
    printf("\nPilha ao final:\n");
    elements(pilha);
    return 0;
}
```

Que vai fazer como está aí, criar a tal pilha, colocar as 26 letrinhas, tirar uma a uma e encerrar. Não escrevi a função que apaga a pilha, mas é trivial.

### o resultado

```
Pilha tem 0 elementos


Pilha tem 26 elementos
z y x w v u t s r q
p o n m l k j i h g
f e d c b a

Topo => 'z' [26 elementos]
Topo => 'y' [25 elementos]
Topo => 'x' [24 elementos]
Topo => 'w' [23 elementos]
Topo => 'v' [22 elementos]
Topo => 'u' [21 elementos]
Topo => 't' [20 elementos]
Topo => 's' [19 elementos]
Topo => 'r' [18 elementos]
Topo => 'q' [17 elementos]
Topo => 'p' [16 elementos]
Topo => 'o' [15 elementos]
Topo => 'n' [14 elementos]
Topo => 'm' [13 elementos]
Topo => 'l' [12 elementos]
Topo => 'k' [11 elementos]
Topo => 'j' [10 elementos]
Topo => 'i' [ 9 elementos]
Topo => 'h' [ 8 elementos]
Topo => 'g' [ 7 elementos]
Topo => 'f' [ 6 elementos]
Topo => 'e' [ 5 elementos]
Topo => 'd' [ 4 elementos]
Topo => 'c' [ 3 elementos]
Topo => 'b' [ 2 elementos]
Topo => 'a' [ 1 elementos]

Pilha ao final:

Pilha tem 0 elementos
```

Depois voltamos a esse programa.

#### No seu programa

```
pilha nova_pilha = (pilha)malloc(sizeof(pilha));
```

Esse é o maior problema no seu código porque `pilha` é um ponteiro então devia ter escrito `sizeof(*pilha)` considerando sua declaração

```
typedef struct pilha_struct* pilha;
```

#### empilha()

O código para empilha() está muito complicado

```
    if (vazia(p))
    {
        pilha_no novo_no = (pilha_no)malloc(sizeof(pilha_no));

        if (!novo_no)
            return (0);

        novo_no->item = item;
        novo_no->prox = NULL;

        p->topo = novo_no;
        p->quantidade++;

        return (1);
    }

    else
    {
        pilha_no novo_no = (pilha_no)malloc(sizeof(pilha_no));

        if (!novo_no)
            return (0);

        novo_no->item = item;
        novo_no->prox = p->topo;
        p->topo = novo_no;
        p->quantidade++;

        return (1);
    }
}
```

Porque usa um else depois do return? Só dificulta a leitura. Um return é definitivo. Não há razão para um else.

E é errado criar algo em `empilha()` quando a pilha está vazia:
apenas chame `inicializa()` aí mesmo. Se você mudar algo em `inicializa()` deixou sempre essa "ponta solta" aí.

Veja como pode ser mais simples

```
Pilha*  empilha(Item* item, Pilha* p)
{
    if (vazia(p)) p = inicializa();
    Node* novo = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    novo->item = *item;
    novo->prox = p->topo;
    p->quantidade += 1;
    p->topo = novo;
    return p;
};  // empilha()
```

e o contrário:

```
int     desempilha(Pilha* p)
{
    if (vazia(p)) return (0);
    Node* segundo = p->topo->prox;
    free(p->topo);
    p->topo = segundo;
    p->quantidade -= 1;
    return p->quantidade;
};  // desempilha()
```

### de volta ao exemplo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef char Item;

typedef struct _node_
{
  Item              item;
  struct    _node_* prox;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned    quantidade;
    Node*       topo;
}   Pilha;

int     desempilha(Pilha*); // tira um POP()
int     elements(Pilha*); // lista todos
Pilha*  empilha(Item*, Pilha*); // poe um PUSH()
Pilha*  inicializa(); // cria
Item*   mostra(Pilha*); // mostra o topo TOP()
int     vazia(Pilha*); // empty()
int     size(Pilha*); // size()

int main()
{
    Pilha* pilha = inicializa();
    elements(pilha);
    for (char item = 'a'; item <= 'z'; item += 1)
        pilha = empilha(&item, pilha);
    elements(pilha);
    while (!vazia(pilha))
    {   mostra(pilha);
        desempilha(pilha);
    };
    printf("\nPilha ao final:\n");
    elements(pilha);
    return 0;
}

int     desempilha(Pilha* p)
{
    if (vazia(p)) return (0);
    Node* segundo = p->topo->prox;
    free(p->topo);
    p->topo = segundo;
    p->quantidade -= 1;
    return p->quantidade;
};  // desempilha()

int     elements(Pilha* pilha)
{
    int col = 0;
    printf("\nPilha tem %d elementos\n", size(pilha));
    Node* p = pilha->topo;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%c ", p->item);
        col += 1;
        if (col % 10 == 0) printf("\n");
        p = p->prox;
    };  // while()
    if (col % 10 != 0) printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    return pilha->quantidade;
};

Pilha*  empilha(Item* item, Pilha* p)
{
    if (vazia(p)) p = inicializa();
    Node* novo = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    novo->item = *item;
    novo->prox = p->topo;
    p->quantidade += 1;
    p->topo = novo;
    return p;
};  // empilha()

Pilha* inicializa()
{
    Pilha* pilha = (Pilha*)malloc(sizeof(Pilha));
    if (pilha == NULL) return (NULL);
    pilha->quantidade = 0;
    pilha->topo = NULL;
    return pilha;
};

Item* mostra(Pilha* p)
{
    if (p == NULL) return NULL;
    if (p->topo == NULL) return NULL;
    printf("Topo => '%c' [%2d elementos]\n",
        p->topo->item, p->quantidade);
    return NULL;
};

int     size(Pilha* p)
{
    return p->quantidade;
}

int     vazia(Pilha* p)
{
    return p->quantidade == 0;
}
```

Compare com esse código. Talvez ache mais legível. Digitei em cima de seu código

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, mas ela foge um pouco da questão. A nomenclatura que foi utilizada nas estruturas não pode ser alterada. Esse é um exercício que meu professor passou, então o nome das funções bem como a definição da estrutura não pode ser mudada. Por isso não utilizei nomenclaturas mais comuns como push e pop. A única coisa que posso alterar é a implementação de cada função. Obrigado por apontar o else depois do return, vou alterar para que fique um pouco mais claro. Tentei mudar para sizeof(*pilha), mas o compilador acusa erro, enquanto da forma que está no programa funciona

Comment: Pelo que testei, a função de empilhar está funcionando corretamente, apesar de apresentar os problemas de clareza que você apontou. O erro ocorre nessa linha da função desempilha:  p->topo = p->topo->prox; Que gera o erro de Segmentation fault.

Comment: Está errado. Que compilador está usando? precisa alocar do tamanho certo. comparou os dois programas? Você está alocando `sizeof(pilha)` que é 4 ou 8. Entenda isso. Então vai cancelar mais cedo ou mais tarde. Tem que alocar o tamanho certo. Se `*pilha` não está bom use `sizeof(struct pilha_struct)`. Eu já te disse 3 vezes que está errado. Use um `printf()` e verá.

Comment: E compare os códigos de seu programa com o que eu alterei. Sua rotina `elements()` está zoando os ponteiros...